# Replace nested for loops in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

can you help me getting rid off the nested for loop?
Array may change all the time, as of right now i need to add/remove for loops. Is it possible with pure bash to replace nested for loops with more elegant solution?

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
array=(A B C)
places=3
word1=word1
word2=word2
arrC=${#array[*]}
while [ $i -lt $((arrC**places)) ]; do
    for a in ${!array[*]}; do
        for b in ${!array[*]}; do
            for c in ${!array[*]}; do
                echo "[$i] ${array[$a]}${word1}${array[$b]}${word2}${array[$c]}"
                i=$((i + 1))
            done
        done
    done
done
```

I've made ABC array for simplicity. Here is more of a real example for an array:
array=(I i L l | \ / 1 !)

Comment: ???? You want to process all combinations of _a/b/c_  in a single loop? Why?

Comment: what is the code trying to do?

Comment: This might be silly but sometimes i'm given passwords that are written badly and this is done through 3-rd hands on a paper. Its faster to check them by myself than its is to get an answer. In addition to that sometimes people that made those passwords don't remember themselves exactly what they wrote. And to remake them there is additional cost to it and time.

Comment: With **GNU Parallel** maybe? `parallel -k echo {#} {1} {2} {3} ::: A B C ::: A B C ::: A B C`

Comment: This does simplify the code for sure `array=(A B C D E) && parallel -k echo {#} {1}word1{2}word2{3}word3 ::: ${array[*]} ::: ${array[*]} ::: ${array[*]}`

Comment: I didn't put it as an answer because you asked for pure bash, but **GNU Parallel** is a great tool in these days of multicore CPUs.

Comment: It surely is the most easy of use solution but its very slow comparing to pure bash. I've never heard of it before, so its a good addition to my tool set. But i didn't give up on bash version yet. Here is what i've got with it, i need to change array and words: 
```
array=(A B C D)
# array=(I i L l '|' '\' '/' 1 !)
words=word0{1}word1{2}word2{3}word3
nA="::: ${array[*]}"
amnA=3
i=0
while [ $i -lt $amnA ]; do
    fA=$(echo $fA $nA)
    i=$((i+1))
done
parallel -k echo {#} $words $fA
```

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
array=(A B C)
words=(word1 word2)

combine () {
    local depth=$1
    local prefix=${2# }
    shift 2
    if ((depth == ${#array[@]})) ; then
        echo "$prefix"
        return
    fi

    local i
    for (( i=1; i<=$#; ++i )) ; do
        combine $((depth+1)) "$prefix${!i}${words[depth]}" "${array[@]}"
    done
}

combine 0 "" "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: If i change array from (A B C) to (A B C D) it works differently than the example i gave.

Comment: @YoloYolovich: You need to change words to (words1 words2 words3) too.

Comment: There maybe 5 letters and 2 words, so its not always n-1 compared to array of letters.

Comment: Oh, do you want to change the final condition to `((depth == 1 + ${#words[@]}))` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at an `awk` solution that uses a recursive function to allow for a dynamic number of `for` loops.

But first a couple mods to the input parameters (to make it easier to pass info into `awk`); we'll replace `bash` level arrays with simple variables (using a `:` as a delimiter for this exercise):

```
array_s="A:B:C:D"
words_s="${word1}:${word2}"
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v places="${places}" -v words_s="${words_s}" -v array_s="${array_s}" '

function print_place(place,outstring, j, sfx) {        # define but do not pass "j" and "sfx"; 
                                                       # this designates these as local variables

if ( place > places )                                  # if we haveve exceeded the number of places ...
   { i++                                               # increment our counter
     printf "%s\n", outstring                          # print our string to stdout
     return                                            # and exit this invocation of the function
   }
if ( i > total ) return                                # if we have exceeded total number of outputs
                                                       # then exit this invocation of the function

sfx=""                                                 # default suffix is "" unless we
if ( place < places ) sfx=words[place]                 # have not reached the max number of places

for ( j=1 ; j<=n ; j++ )                               # loop through arr[] entries
    print_place(place+1,outstring arr[j] sfx)          # recursive function call for place+1; also pass along 
                                                       # our growing string
}

BEGIN { n=split(array_s,arr,":")                       # parse "array_s" into awk array "arr[]"
        m=split(words_s,words,":")                     # parse "words_s" into awak array "words[]"
        total=n**places                                # calculate total number of strings to print

        i=0                                            # init counter
        print_place(1,"")                              # call function
}
'
```

Some sample runs:

```
places=3
array_s="A:B:C"
words_s="word1:word2"

awk ...

Aword1Aword2A
Aword1Aword2B
Aword1Aword2C
Aword1Bword2A
Aword1Bword2B
Aword1Bword2C
...snip...
Cword1Cword2A
Cword1Cword2B
Cword1Cword2C                        # 27 lines of output

##############

places=2
array_s="A:B:C:D"
words_s="word1:word2"

awk ...

Aword1A
Aword1B
Aword1C
Aword1D
Bword1A
Bword1B
Bword1C
Bword1D
Cword1A
Cword1B
Cword1C
Cword1D
Dword1A
Dword1B
Dword1C
Dword1D                        # 16 lines of output

##############

places=4
array_s="A:B:C:D"
words_s="word1:word2:word3"

awk ...

Aword1Aword2Aword3A
Aword1Aword2Aword3B
Aword1Aword2Aword3C
Aword1Aword2Aword3D
Aword1Aword2Bword3A
Aword1Aword2Bword3B
Aword1Aword2Bword3C
Aword1Aword2Bword3D
Aword1Aword2Cword3A
Aword1Aword2Cword3B
...snip...
Dword1Dword2Cword3D
Dword1Dword2Dword3A
Dword1Dword2Dword3B
Dword1Dword2Dword3C
Dword1Dword2Dword3D                        # 256 lines of output
```